# Vim powerline (Lokaltog's) weird characters in MacVim

Tags: vim, plugins, fonts

I'm trying to use Powerline plugin (https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) for the first time.

Plugin seems to be installed. I use vundle with the following command:

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp':  'powerline/bindings/vim'}
```

I've tried many different settings, but currently in my vimrc it looks like this:

```
set guifont=Menlo\ Regular\ for\ Powerline:h15
"set guifont=Monaco\ Regular:h15
" set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/powerline/powerline/bindings/vim
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
"let g:Powerline_symbols = 'compatible'
"let g:Powerline_cache_enabled = 1
"set t_Co=256
```

I've also pasted commented out some of the commands I've tried.

I've tried different fonts, patched and normal, but nothing helps.

laststatus is set to 2.

I'm using MacVim on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Here's how the powerline with 2 windows looks for me:

[image: powerline with 2 windows]

Note the weird boxed 'x' symbols...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're referring to two different plugins. `vim-powerline` is the old vim-only project. `Lokaltog/powerline` is a new Python-based port, and the code points have changed in this version because the old code points caused a bunch of issues.

You'll have to either:

1. Update your bundle to point to `vim-powerline` (and remove the `rtp` option), or
2. Update your font to one of the fonts in https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts (or patch your own)

Comment: Mine was fixed by option #1 , now it looks like this:

`Plugin 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I downloaded "Menlo Regular for Powerline.otf" from https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts

I then double clicked on the otf file, which opens up the Font Book application. I clicked install, despite the font giving gibberish symbols in the window. I then set that font as the font for my terminal (simply set it in your termnial preferenes). This fixed the problem in regular terminal vim (`$ vim`), but did not fix it in MacVim. To fix it in MacVim, I had to add the following line to my .vimrc file:

```
set guifont=Menlo\ For\ Powerline
```

The backslashes are necessary to escape the spaces. Everything works great now. Hope this helps others.

Edit: To add a bit more detail, my .vimrc looks like this now:

```
""" FOR STATUSLINE
set encoding=utf-8 " Necessary to show Unicode glyphs
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
set rtp+=/Users/nate/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim
set nocompatible   " Disable vi-compatibility
set laststatus=2   " Always show the statusline
" For powerline font in MacVim
set guifont=Menlo\ For\ Powerline
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using command-line vim (i.e. not a GUI implementation) you may need to specify the patched font in your terminal's preferences.

Answer (score 1):

adding this to the vimrc file fixed it for me:

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline "make sure to escape the spaces in the name properly
```

Source: https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have the right fonts not just the right name get them from https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts
and that 
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
that if your using airline

Note:For example "Source code pro" font from http://fontsquirrel.com will give this effect but the "Source code pro for powerline" from the link above will not

Answer (score 0):

In my case, fonts in the status bar were working in vim (displaying the proper symbols) but not in macvim. Added the following line to the .gvimrc file and it works fine now.

I had specify :h16

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline:h16
```

[image]