# Configuring Powerline fonts in vim on Mac 10.8

Tags: macos, vim, fonts

I am trying to get the custom fonts from [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts) to work with [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline). I am running vim 7.4, compiled with Macports, on Mac OS 10.8.

I'm using [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) to install [powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) (and other tools not shown here):

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline', {'rtp': 'powerline/bindings/vim/'}
```

I've downloaded the [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts) repo, and successfully installed the fonts into Font Book. I then added the following to `vimrc`:

```
set encoding=utf8
set termencoding=utf8
set guifont=Droid\ Sans\ Mono\ for\ Powerline:h14
let g:Powerline_symbols='unicode'
set t_Co=256
set laststatus=2
set noshowmode
set fillchars+=stl:\ ,stlnc:\
```

However, when I run vim, I am greeted with box symbols instead of arrows, as shown below (taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250147/vim-powerline-lokaltogs-weird-characters-in-macvim)).

[image: Image of Box symbols in vim with powerline]

I have tried to switch the fonts around, and have used all of the fonts available from [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts), but there is never any difference. In fact, changing `guifont` to `Wingdings:h14` has no effect.

How do I check that vim can support powerline? How may I get fonts working correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer since installing the fonts? It sounds stupid, but on linux when I had this problem (setting my terminal font, not the guifont) updating the font cache with `fc-cache -vf` and restarting my terminal was not enough. Try restarting if you haven't yet.

Comment: "Is it plugged in?" :P

I've restarted the computer several times, just to make sure. No dice. However, your comment about terminal font and guifont put me on the right track. Turns out I'm being dense: I never changed the terminal font, and given that I'm running vim in a console, `guifont` has no effect (as there is no gui).

Comment: Did you change your terminal emulator's font?

Comment: When I wrote the question: no, I had not. @blueblob helped me realize that's where the problem was, as discussed in my answer below. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks your vimrc options helped me.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**: change the terminal font if running vim in a console (`guifont` does nothing).

**Longer Answer**:

In `vim --version` I've discovered the line: `Huge version without GUI.`

Opening vim and checking `:help guifont` further shows that the option is `{only available when compiled with GUI enabled}`.

When running vim directly in a console, such as Terminal, vim does not have the ability to control the font, [as discussed in the comment section here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font). In this instance, the solution to my problem is simply to change the font of the entire console, available in Terminal under Preferences->Settings->Text.

It is possible to compile vim via Macports with `+gtk2`, but I was unable to get `guifont` to have any effect.

Hope this helps others avoid a simple mistake.

Comment: I have used vim-airline for a year and the fonts only worked fine in MacVim. I never thought of changing the font in the app settings to make it work in the Terminal app. Thank you!!