# powerline fonts doesn't work on vim/debian

Tags: vim, powerline

I have clone the repos of powerfonts and install it. And I config my vim as

```
let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1
```

However it doesn't work on debian, even I clean the font cache and restart server. But it does work on my mac.

I wonder what's wrong with it. Should I config font on debian?

Comment: Have you set powerline patched font for your terminal emulator?

Comment: @sudobangbang I use item2， it seems ok on my mac/terminal vim, however when I use ssh connect to debian , it doesn't work well.  Should I set font on item2?

Comment: If it works correctly in iterm and if you're using the same to ssh, it should work. but it's worth a try

Comment: @sudobangbang I have checked my item2 fonts, it use powerfonts. So I think there's something wrong with debian config.

Comment: Might be a locale problem. Try configuring font on debian. If that doesn't work, try these http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189133/font-ssh-interaction and 
http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:localization

Comment: @sudobangbang thanks a lot, I will try it.

Comment: @sudobangbang finally solved, using export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" to .zshrc

Comment: Awesome. So client was using `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Powerline fonts in vim on Mac 10.8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963445/configuring-powerline-fonts-in-vim-on-mac-10-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a locale issue.

> A locale is a set of language and cultural rules.  These cover aspects such as language for
>   messages, different character sets, lexicographic conventions, and so on.  A  program  needs
>   to be able to determine its locale and act accordingly to be portable to different cultures.

You can set language using these environment variables

- LANG
- LANGUAGE
- LINGUAS
- LC_COLLATE
- LC_ALL

In this case, setting `LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"` in `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or `.bash_profile` will solve the problems.

or you can set  `LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: please remove the blank spaces on `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`